# how attach image to mail?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, sendmail

please help solve the problem.

i install gem 'paperclip' and add fields to table 'sends':

```
create_table "sends", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.text     "message"
  t.string   "subject"
  t.string   "image_file_name"
  t.string   "image_content_type"
  t.integer  "image_file_size"
  t.datetime "image_updated_at"
end
```

i need send mail with attachment.
app/mailers/send_mailer.rb:

```
class SendMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'no-reply@kalinin.ru'

  def sends_send(send, email)
    @send = send
    @email = email
    @image_name = send.image_file_name     
    @image_path = send.image.url(:medium)     

    p '================================='
    p @image_name
    p @image_path

    mail.attachments[@image_name] = File.read(@image_path)
    mail(to: email.email, subject: send.subject)
  end  
end
```

but after run sends_send, console displays follow:

```
"================================="
"296_197.png"
"/system/sends/images/000/000/012/medium/296_197.png?1444228995"
  Rendered send_mailer/sends_send.html.erb within layouts/mailer (0.1ms)

SendMailer#sends_send: processed outbound mail in 4.7ms
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 9ms (ActiveRecord: 0.3ms)
```

and browser displays follow:

> Errno::ENOENT in SendsController#send_up No such file or directory -
>   /system/sends/images/000/000/012/medium/296_197.png?1444228995

please help attach image to mail.

development.rb:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost', port: 3000 }
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
```

also i set permission for catalog 'public' 777 recursive and try:

```
class SendMailer < ApplicationMailer
  default from: 'no-reply@kalinin.ru'

  def sends_send(send, email)
    @send = send
    @email = email
    @image_name = send.image_file_name     
    #@image_path = send.image.url(:medium)  
    @image_path = '/public' + send.image.url(:medium).split('?').first   

    p '================================='
    p @image_name
    p @image_path

    mail.attachments[@image_name] = File.read(@image_path)
    mail(to: email.email, subject: send.subject)
  end  
end
```

but browser displays:

> No such file or directory -
>   /public/system/sends/images/000/000/012/medium/296_197.png

but this file is exist on HDD

Answer (score 0):

Do you really have a file with name `/system/sends/images/000/000/012/medium/296_197.png?1444228995`? It seems you need to strip everything after `.png`, i.e. question sign and other numbers. Try this:

```
@image_path = send.image.url(:medium).split('?').first
```

Comment: yes, i really have this file on HDD. 
split('?').first is not solve the problem